# Are reserved GPT or UEFI partitions important for data USB disks?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

Will creating a reserved partition on a data USB disk cause problems such as:

- files are too long,
- cannot be deleted or copied,
- files and folders duplicating themselves tenfold,
- etc.

Do I need to create a reserved GPT or UEFI partition on data disks?

I have  2 factory formatted drives from Seagate - brand new - and I had a lot of problems with it.

I thought that if I deleted the GPT or UEFI partitions the drive would work better.

Is this correct?

However, I reinstalled windows a few days ago, and now it seems these problems are gone.

I just initialized an MBR disk to a GPT disk:

- How can I create the reserved partition?
- Should I change something in the BIOS?

I am using EaseUS partition maker.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Please try and ask 1 question at a time (otherwise your question will be closed at too broad). In addition there is no need to shout (use all caps) in your title.

Answer (score 1):

You don't NEED to, but if the disks are larger than 2TB then you'd need to have GPT on them to use more than 2TB of the space.

GPT is much newer and should be preferred over MBR, the only exception being compatibility. GPT may not be recognized on very old systems.

With regard to your second question, there shouldn't be a reserved partition for data disks, it is only needed for OS partitions, and if it is indeed an OS partition we are talking about, it should be created already by the installer.